# Line ends at wrong location in picture environment

Tags: graphics, latex-base, picture-mode

I draw a yellow square inside a grey square, exactly in the middle. Unexpectedly, the yellow square is not aligned horizontally but instead moved to the right:

[image]

Why? If I understand correctly, the yellow square should end at x=37, and the grey at x=38.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\hrule\noindent

\begin{picture}(40,40)
\linethickness{36mm}
\color{gray}
\put(2,20){\line(1,0){36}}

\linethickness{34mm}
\color{yellow}
\put(3,20){\line(1,0){34}}
\end{picture}

\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to terminate your lines with `%` to prevent spurious white space. In particular, putting one after `\linethickness{34mm}` will correct the alignment of the yellow and grey squares, but the other lines should also be terminated with `%`, otherwise both rectangles move too far to the right.

Comment: @Jake Can you explain this further or give a link to an example/explanation?

Comment: @Jost: [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)

Comment: Thanks you, somehow I completely did not expect, that an image-environment could be whitespace-sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture mode commands make some attempt to ignore white space between the instructions but `\color` defeats that attempt so you are seeing the word space after `\color` (and other places). Note that TeX is designed as a text typesetting language promarily and white space is not syntactic decoration as in most programming languages, it is (usually) an *instruction* to add stretchable inter-word space at that point.

It is best to avoid typesetting anything in picture mode that is not inside `\put` so

```
\color{yellow}
\put(3,20){\line(1,0){34}}
```

not

```
\put(3,20){\color{yellow}\line(1,0){34}}
```

Although `\color` is in fact safe outside `\put` as long as you avoid adding space around it

```
\color{yellow}%
```

---

The definition of `\linethickness` has been changed (2020 release) to avoid this extra space.

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/274